# Vanilla Javascript: To-do List Not Creating li Upon Clicking Submit Button and event.preventDefault() Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, submit, jsfiddle

I am following Dev Ed's beginner to-do list guide using Vanilla Javascript. I couldn't find answers to my question in the YouTube comments, so I'm asking here.

To summarize, I want:

1. To get a result that looks like the first picture and not the second picture, which is what I'm currently getting upon opening in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
2. Understand why event.preventDefault() isn't working and why the page keeps refreshing when clicking the + button.

In his https://github.com/developedbyed/vanilla-todo the code works perfectly in jsfiddle.com but in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, it doesn't seem to have the same result when I open it up in Visual Studio Code > Open with Live Server.

[image: What It Should Look Like]

[image: What It Looks Like For Me In Chrome, Firefox, and Opera]

I am stuck in his video from 23:40  - I don't get a "hey" line when clicking the + button. https://youtu.be/Ttf3CEsEwMQ?t=1420. When I click on the + button, the page refreshes. event.preventDefault() doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code from the video up to that point:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0- 
   2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-46r060N2LrChLLb5zowXQ72/iKKNiw/lAmygmHExk/o=" 
crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<header>
    <h1>My Todo List</h1> 
</header>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input"> 
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
     <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>   
    </button>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
    <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
    <script scr="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
//Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton= document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

//Event Listeners
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
//Functions
event.preventDefault();
    //Prevent form from submitting
//Todo DIV
const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
//Create LI
const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
newTodo.innerText = "hey";
newTodo.classList.add("todo-item");
todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
//CHECK MARK BUTTON
const completedButton = document.createElement("button");
completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
//CHECK trash BUTTON
const trashButton = document.createElement("button");
trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
//APPEND TO LIST
todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
}
```

CSS:

```
    * { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #e2c35d, #d88771);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
header {
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}

header,form {
    min-height: 20vh;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

form input, form button {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 2 rem;
    border: none;
    background: white;
}

form button {
    color: #d88771;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
form button:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #d88771;
    
}
```

Comment: You forgot to define your `addToDo` function.

Comment: Also, be sure to use the console in your developer tools. This will be your new favorite part of the browser which will tell you loads of (although somewhat cryptic at first) info when something goes wrong. Every browser has it. You should check it out. It might tell you *why* it is not working. And that will help you solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you! But even now the event.preventDefault() isn't working. Here is what I have so far: https://imgur.com/a/UAEBHCq

Answer (score 0):

Forms that have a `<button type="submit">` in them will submit when you click on that button. This means that you'll have to cancel the default behavior of the `<form>`, not the `<button>`. I would suggest using this method because it allows you control over how the form behaves, instead of just how the button behaves. It also allows you to use the <kbd>return</kbd> key on your keyboard to submit the form.

Select the form element in JavaScript, give it an id if you have to make it easier to select, and listen for the `submit` event on the form that you've selected.

Now what you want to happen is that the `addTodo` function is called every time you click the submit button. That is what the `addEventListener` part is for. There you can monitor an event, like a submit in this case, and act upon it whenever that happens. So listen for the submit event on the form and call `addTodo` when that event is fired.

If you use `addEventListener` **inside** your `addTodo` function, then you'll add a new listener every time `addTodo` is called, and that's bad!

Check out the example below to see how it works.

```js
//Selectors - Also select the form.
const todoForm = document.querySelector("#todo-form");
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

// Listen for the submit event and call addTodo when a submit happens.
todoForm.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);

function addTodo(event) {
  //Functions
  event.preventDefault();
  //Prevent form from submitting
  //Todo DIV
  const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
  //Create LI
  const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add("todo-item");
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  //CHECK MARK BUTTON
  const completedButton = document.createElement("button");
  completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
  completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  //CHECK trash BUTTON
  const trashButton = document.createElement("button");
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
  trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
  //APPEND TO LIST
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>My Todo List</h1>
</header>
<form id="todo-form">
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation- however, when I put the exact same code you mentioned into Visual Studio Code and right click > Open with Live Server, the refreshing still occurs upon clicking the Add button. I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: That probably means that JavaScript encountered an error in the script. Open up the developer tools in your browser and check the console. There you will see an error that tells you what the error is. The console will be your new best friend, so get familiar.

Comment: Thanks, it's showing https://imgur.com/a/fLiPNVu and the app.js in the Sources tab of Dev Chrome Tools looks different from the one posted above. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Nope, seems like you are using a different script than you've presented us with. Try to figure out where the `src` of the script leads to and if it refers the correct file.

Comment: So the issue I'm noticing now is that opening the file using http://localhost:5500/ and opening the index.html locally on my machine yields different results. Seems that the script isn't loading when opening from http://localhost:5500/ even when Live Server is active (I'm using Visual Studio Code).

Answer (score -1):

make a addTodo function and

```
todoButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //event.preventDefault()
    addTodo();
});
```